# How to estimate the size of cache with a threaded program?

Tags: multithreading, caching

If I don't know the size of cache and have a threaded program,

I can obtain GFLOPS by running the program with increasing the number of threads.

How can I estimate the size of cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a byte buffer of size `N`, then perform a lot of *random* reads on it (let say `20*N` and finally measure the resulting time of the random reads. The performance of the random operation is directly dependent of `N` and the cache size: when data fit in cache, the reads are much faster because data can be retrieved *locally*. You should divide the time by the number of reads to know approximately the **amortized latency per read**.

Because most processors have multiple levels of cache, the result you should get is something like that:

[image]

You can see on the plot the impact of the different level of the memory hierarchy (L1, L2, L3 and the RAM). **The performance gaps let you know the cache sizes and the number of cache in the hierarchy**. For example, in the above plot, the L1 cache is likely of size 32KB. If you want to do it automatically, you can just locate the local maximum of the derivative function. If you want something more accurate, you could use some basic *machine-learning methods*.